# Ubuntu server - how to stay on lts version?

Tags: 16.04, server, updates

We are using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server edition. During installation automatic updates was enabled. After installation OS service packs were updated and everything went on smoothly.

We suddenly got updates available notice when login in to the server. Got suspicious because it said 454 updates available and machine was updated two days back after building so tried updating on mirror machine. This resulted into OS update - that is jumping from 16.04.3 to 17.10. We did not do release-upgrade, but apt-get update.

Strangely this problem does not show on older 16.04 machines with same settings. We downloaded current ISO file from ubuntu servers and only servers built with new ISO show this problem.

File /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades shows value lts

I know UI has settings where it will prompt for LTS versions only or only do updates for current version.

What is the equivalent setting I need to do on the server edition?

If the server is already informing me about available (but not installed) updates, can this setting change do right thing and update only 16.04 related entries and not update the release version?

Comment: if you're not running `do-release-upgrade` command I doubt it's going to upgrade your distro to a newer version you will stay on LTS.

Comment: do you possibly have something located in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/` that is overriding the settings?

Comment: At least the desktop versions of 16.04.1 LTS (the first point release) will stay with the xenial kernel (4.4 series, now at 4.4.0-103-generic #126-Ubuntu). I think Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS will behave like that too, and refrain not only from do-release-upgrades but also from upgrading the hardware enablement stack and switch to new kernel series. You can find Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/ and it has support until April 2021 (5 years of support).

Comment: @JohnOrion, directory /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ is empty.

Comment: ok just wanted to make sure there wasn't something overriding the lts in there ... don't know what the issue may be in that case .. im sure there are much more knowledgeable people here that will help

Comment: @JoKeR - As I said, it does not happen on older 16.04 machines. Just now noticed same thing on one of the recently built amazon vm too.

Comment: @sudodus, yes, I use 16.04 desktop and have not experienced this.

Comment: Try with the **first point release** 16.04.1 LTS. It behaves differently  from the second and third point releases. Chances are that the server version of the first point release will work like this too.